# Can I fix legal question 329974?

Tags: discussion

My [question about Skyrim's new terms of service](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/329974) has been closed. I couldn't find online references for the terms or their changes (e.g. on https://tosdr.org ), so I was hoping this would be a valid use of the [legal] tag.

Is there anything I can do to salvage the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your question is regarding a translation of a legal document, which is off topic. The only way I can see your questions being back on topic is:

Let's say for instance you are using a plugin or mod that does something to the game's files, you can ask if that is illegal now. You must pinpoint your exact issue with a possible update to the ToS that once was okay but now may not be.

The legal tag is mostly used for asking questions about legal ways to play games that don't exist, ways to use gaming software in regards to EULA's and ToS's and about a specific part of a legal document. Simply asking for a diff on version numbers is off topic.